# Hpw to get file from dxFileUploader

Tags: typescript, devexpress, devextreme

I try to get file from dxFileUploader (DevExpress), but I can't read this file on code behind. I see only object
My FileUploader :

```
 {
                    location: "before",
                    widget: "dxFileUploader",
                    options: {
                        multiple: false,
                        accept: "*",
                        value: [],
                        uploadMode: "instantly",
                        onValueChanged: (e) => {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "api/CoordinateSystems/UploadFile",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: e.value,
                                error(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    DxExtensions.notifyAjaxError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
                                    DxExtensions.error(errorThrown);
                                },
                                success(data) {
                                    dataSource.load();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Codebehind:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadFile")]
    public IActionResult UploadFile(dynamic file)
    {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>(); // added this just to return something

        if (file != null)
        {

            string physicalWebRootPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
            // do something
        }

        return  Ok();
    }
```

How to get file, which I can save on server and work with it?

Comment: What is e.value?

Comment: @Musa, It may be wrong, I don\t know what i must send on DATA

Comment: Maybe **[this](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FileUploader/FileUploading/NetCore/Light/)** is helpful

Comment: See the use of `HttpPostedFileBase` at https://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

This is AngularJS but you can use part of it

HTML

```
<div dx-file-uploader="{
                                buttonText: 'Select file',
                                labelText: 'Drop file here',
                                multiple: false,
                                uploadMode: 'instantly',
                                bindingOptions: { uploadUrl: 'UploadUrl' ,disabled : 'IsReadOnly'},
                                showFileList: false,
                                onUploaded: on_Uploaded,
                                onInitialized: on_Initialized
                            }"></div>
```

UploadUrl

```
$scope.UploadUrl = CTHelper.ApiUrl() + '/Api/Case/PostFile';
```

API

```
[Route("Api/Case/PostFile")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFile()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

            try
            {
                var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Api.Helper.Constants.PortalFilesVirtualDir);
                foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
                {
                    var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                    var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("{0}/{1}", path, filename), buffer);
                    //Do whatever you want with filename and its binaray data.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                message.Content = new StringContent(err.Message);
                throw new HttpResponseException(message);
            }
            return Ok();

        }
```